# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!n^n}\right)^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!n^n}\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2):

Given $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!\cdot n^n}\bigg]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Using stirling approximation $$n!=\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg[\frac{\bigg(\frac{3n}{e}\bigg)^{3n}\sqrt{6\pi n}}{\bigg(\frac{2n}{e}\bigg)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}\cdot n^n}\Bigg]^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{27}{4e}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{6\pi n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{27}{4e}.$$

Comment: You mean:  $\enspace\displaystyle n!\approx\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\enspace$

Comment: Some $e$ got lost in the last passage.